# Mails flagged as ****spam***

Tags: exim

I have Exim mail server. Mails generated by PHP code are flagged as spam in mail subject. Please help to stop that ****spam**** subject in my mail which generated by PHP code.

Comment: You might be interested in this thread: http://serverfault.com/questions/48428/how-to-send-emails-and-avoid-them-being-classified-as-spam

Answer (score 1):

The `****spam***` tag is used by default by SpamAssassin to mark messages flagged as spam. If your PHP is sending the mail through a local mail server, disable spam filtering on that server (or add the PHP mailer to the exception/whitelist).

Answer (score 0):

You should set up *SPF* and *DKIM* authentications to stop emails be considered as *SPAM*.

- *SPF* consists in adding a *TXT DNS record* to your domain.
- *DKIM* consists in setting up *MTA* (Mail Transfert Agent) such as *Exim* and adding a *TXT DNS record* to your domain.

See [Create and configure DNS records for a domain](http://en.open-lamp.com/create-and-configure-dns-records-for-a-domain/) and [Authenticate emails with DKIM on Debian or Ubuntu Linux](http://en.open-lamp.com/authenticate-emails-with-dkim-on-debian-or-ubuntu-linux/) for more details.